# I'm getting a null pointer exception error

Tags: android, android-location, currentlocation

I get a Null pointer exception error in the getLatitude and getLongitude area of the code.How do I resolve this.
That's been my major challenge. Please help as it's causing much upset since my app keeps crashing everytime

```
package www.uneditedmap.com.locationandmap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Restaurant extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {
    private final int MAX_PLACES = 20;
    private GoogleMap theMap;
    private LocationManager locMan;
    private Marker userMarker;
    private int defautltId, restaurantId;
    private Marker[] placeMarkers;
    private MarkerOptions[] places;
    String apiKey;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_map);
        defautltId = R.drawable.ic_default;
        restaurantId = R.drawable.ic_restaurant;

        apiKey = getResources().getString(R.string.google_maps_key);

        if (theMap == null) {
            //map not instantiated yet
            theMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.the_map)).getMap();
            if (theMap != null) {
                //ok - proceed
                theMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
                placeMarkers = new Marker[MAX_PLACES];
                //update places
                updatePlaces();
            }
        }
    }

    private void updatePlaces() {
//update location
        locMan = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location lastLoc = locMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
       if (lastloc != null) {
           double lat = lastLoc.getLatitude();
           double lng = lastLoc.getLongitude();
       }
        LatLng lastLatLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        if (userMarker != null) {
            userMarker.remove();
        }
        userMarker = theMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(lastLatLng)
                .title("You are here")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(defautltId))
                .snippet("Your last recorded location"));
        theMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(lastLatLng), 3000, null);

        String placesSearchStr = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/" +
                "json?location=" + lat + "," + lng +
                    "&radius=3000" +
                    "&types=food|bar" + "&key=" + apiKey +  "&sensor=true";


        //Reference for searching through url
        //https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/
        // json?radius=200&key=AIzaSyDPVYhZDzHdxRGnqqHZSWccL-BEe-JSYXA
        // &location=-33.86705220%2C151.19573620&keyword=attractions

        //My Add
//        https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/
//         json?location=51.503186,-0.126446&radius=1000&sensor=true&types=food|bar
//         &key=AIzaSyCBQyZ8lxV5vmLDMQRAuVBHIeBGnURpfCo&keyword=restaurants

        //Reference add
        //https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?
        // location=51.503186,-0.126446&radius=5000
        // &keyword=health&key=AIzaSyCshx_mxH4pJlxZAEfdHK4o012zZfitwX0

        new GetPlaces().execute(placesSearchStr);
        locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 30000, 100, this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (theMap != null) {
            locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 30000, 100, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (theMap != null) {
            locMan.removeUpdates(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.v("Restaurant", "location changed");
        updatePlaces();

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.v("Restaurant", "provider disabled");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.v("Restaurant", "provider enabled");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.v("Restaurant", "status changed");
    }

    private class GetPlaces extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        //fetch and parse place data
        //yak4woundei@yahoo.com
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... placesURL) {
            //fetch places
            StringBuilder placesBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            //process search parameter string(s)
            for (String placeSearchURL : placesURL) {
                //execute search
                HttpClient placesClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                try {
                    //try to fetch the data
                    HttpGet placesGet = new HttpGet(placeSearchURL);
                    HttpResponse placesResponse = placesClient.execute(placesGet);
                    StatusLine placeSearchStatus = placesResponse.getStatusLine();
                    if (placeSearchStatus.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                        //we have an OK response
                        HttpEntity placesEntity = placesResponse.getEntity();
                        InputStream placesContent = placesEntity.getContent();
                        InputStreamReader placesInput = new InputStreamReader(placesContent);
                        BufferedReader placesReader = new BufferedReader(placesInput);
                        String lineIn;
                        while ((lineIn = placesReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            placesBuilder.append(lineIn);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return placesBuilder.toString();
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //parse place data returned from Google Places
            if (placeMarkers != null) {
                for (int pm = 0; pm < placeMarkers.length; pm++) {
                    if (placeMarkers[pm] != null)
                        placeMarkers[pm].remove();
                }
            }
            try {
                //parse JSON

                JSONObject resultObject = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray placesArray = resultObject.getJSONArray("results");
                places = new MarkerOptions[placesArray.length()];
                //loop through places
                for (int p = 0; p < placesArray.length(); p++) {
                    //parse each place
                    boolean missingValue = false;
                    LatLng placeLL = null;
                    String placeName = "";
                    String vicinity = "";
                    int currIcon = restaurantId;

                    try {
                        //attempt to retrieve place data values
                        missingValue = false;
                        JSONObject placeObject = placesArray.getJSONObject(p);
                        JSONObject loc = placeObject.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location");
                        placeLL = new LatLng(
                                Double.valueOf(loc.getString("lat")),
                                Double.valueOf(loc.getString("lng")));
                        JSONArray types = placeObject.getJSONArray("types");
                        for (int t = 0; t < types.length(); t++) {
                            //what type is it
                            String thisType = types.get(t).toString();
                            if (thisType.contains("food")) {
                                currIcon = restaurantId;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        vicinity = placeObject.getString("vicinity");
                        placeName = placeObject.getString("name");

                    } catch (JSONException jse) {
                        missingValue = true;
                        jse.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (missingValue) places[p] = null;
                    else
                        places[p] = new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(placeLL)
                                .title(placeName)
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(currIcon))
                                .snippet(vicinity);

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (places != null && placeMarkers != null) {
                for (int p = 0; p < places.length && p < placeMarkers.length; p++) {
                    //will be null if a value was missing
                    if (places[p] != null)
                        placeMarkers[p] = theMap.addMarker(places[p]);
                }
            }
        }


    }


}
```

Log cat:

```
11-17 20:30:40.532  17851-17851/www.uneditedmap.com.locationandmap E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: www.uneditedmap.com.locationandmap, PID: 17851
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{www.uneditedmap.com.locationandmap/www.uneditedmap.com.locationandmap.Restaurant}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at www.uneditedmap.com.locationandmap.Restaurant.updatePlaces(Restaurant.java:71)
            at www.uneditedmap.com.locationandmap.Restaurant.onCreate(Restaurant.java:62)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `defautltId==null` check it

Comment: I think you should also take locations from the map ,

Comment: in (lastloc != null) , what is lastloc. ?

Comment: solved it already. thanks all.